# How to do cascading addition of dates in Excel

Tags: excel, project-planning, excel-formula

The excel should behave in the following way:
[image]

My Start Date is yet unknown. The advantage I'm seeking is If I change the Start Date. I would like the excel to update all other dates based on the criteria. There will not be any holidays in between the plan. Except the Saturdays and Sundays.

I tried the Workday function, but, I'm unable to track the remaining date from the past row's due date.

Comment: please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Here it is. I've added one column called remaining days. Which is a number column

1st Row's `DueDate = 1st Start Date + Total` 
1st Row's `RemainDays = NetWorkDays(1st startDate, 1st DueDate) - Total no. of days`

from 2nd Row onwards `startDate = if(previous row remaining < 0.1, workdays(previous due date,1), previous due date)`
from 2nd Row onwards `dueDate = start date + Total` same for all the rows...
from 2nd Row onwards `remainingDays = NetWorkDays(startDate, DueDate) - total - previous row due date`

Excel is magical...